# Disable Javascript in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Is there any plug-in/way to disable java-script inside tinymce ? I don't want people to allow  tags or any inline java-scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [valid_elements](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_elements) option:

> The valid_elements option defines
>   which elements will remain in the
>   edited text when the editor saves. You
>   can use this to limit the returned
>   HTML to a subset.
>
> This option contains a comma separated
>   list of element conversion chunks.
>   Each chunk contains information about
>   how one element and its attributes
>   should be treated. The default rule
>   set for this option is specified
>   below.

Comment: I tried Invalid_elements added script to it which works fine inside body but it doesnt remove it from head.

Answer (score 3):

This issue were been raised as security vulnerability issue and We were using 3.4.9 version of tinymce.Using below snippet we fixed this issue.

```
tinyMCE.init({
 invalid_elements : "script",
});
```

Refer tinymce wiki http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:invalid_elements

Comment: The link above doesn't work. Here is the current link to that option
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#invalid_elements

Comment: In my case I am allowing everything and just want to prevent JS. See below working sample for better idea. 

Working Fiddle: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/WRhaab/2

valid_elements: '*[*]',
invalid_elements: 'script'

If I keep both then tinymce doesn't prevent JS but if I remove valid_elements then tinymce works fine but I need to keep invalid_elements so not sure what to do. Can anyone help?