# "invalid_elements" not working when we have "valid_elements" in Tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-5

I have a scenario in which we have defined valid and invalid elements in Tinymce. Below are the values of these two:

```
invalid_elements: 'script',
valid_elements: '*[*]',
```

"invalid_elements" is to prevent JavaScript to be entered. With above settings, Tinymce is not preventing JavaScript but if I remove "valid_elements" then it starts working.

I am not sure if I remove "valid_elements" still Tinymce will allow everything and that's why keeping "valid_element".

Tinymce version: 5.6.2

Related question but not helping in my scenario: [Disable Javascript in TinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204870/disable-javascript-in-tinymce)

Working Fiddle: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/WRhaab/2

Is there any way by which I can keep "valid_elements" and prevent JavaScript as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`valid_elements` and `invalid_elements` are not exclusive options. They can work together but can't contradict each other.

When you are setting `valid_elements` to `'*[*]'`, it means all elements are allowed. If all elements are valid, scripts are valid too. That's why if you remove the `valid_elements` option, `invalid_elements` starts working.

If you are not sure some elements would stay valid if `valid_elements: '*[*]'` is removed, you can check [HTML 5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/) and [HTML 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/) specifications since by default TinyMCE allows all elements specified by these standards. You can use the [`schema`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#schema) option to switch between different standards.

Comment: So, does `'*[*]'` is same as **default value** of valid_elements, in other words does `'*[*]'` same as **not defining** valid_elements as all?

Comment: No, it is not. Setting valid_elements to `'*[*]'` actually means disabling all validation. It is equivalent to `verify_html: false`. And it is actually very dangerous in terms of security. Usually, the combination of `valid_elements` and `invalid_elements` works like "accept all `valid_elements` except `invalid_elements`", but `'*[*]'` is the exception.